# Netbeans 7.4 Griffon support

Tags: groovy, griffon, netbeans-7.4

I'm new to Griffon.

But I installed Grails and currently creating projects on Grails in NB7.4. Because there is a default option in NB7.4. Grails working smooth.

Now(at this time of writing) in NB plugin portal there is a griffon plugin. But it supports only for NB7.1. I tried installing it on NB7.4, but it throws many errors while creating projects.(Project not created - It cannot create a project).

How to create Griffon apps on NB7.4. I tried google, but there is no support for NB7.4.

**Help me on this topic. Also i need your suggestions and tips to run Griffon on NB7.4.**

**Hint:** Actuall I'm trying to upgrade to Groovy-Griffon. Now I'm creating apps for shops on JavaSwing. I read Griffon it is amazing, so i planned to upgrade my work and knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Up to now(at the time of writing this) NB Griffon Plugin is not updated to support NB7.4**.

NB7.4 have inbuilt support for Grails. I can create Grails apps directly.

NB Griffon plugin needs to be updated for NB7.4. Or NB team needs to add this support.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that the NetBeans Griffon plugin doesn't work very well with latest versions of NetBeans. This is due to changes made back in Griffon 0.9.5 on how dependencies are resolved.
Griffon doesn't really need an IDE but if you must then allow me to suggest you IntelliJ IDEA; the community edition comes with a Griffon plugin that works much better.

But you still have to resolve dependencies out side of IDEA, that is, calling the `griffon --integrate-with --idea` command from the command line, every time you update `BuildConfig.groovy` or install/uninstall a griffon plugin on your project.

Comment: *Is IntelliJ IDEA better than NB for Groovy,Grails,Griffon?* If so I'l install IntelliJ IDEA. I'm working on NB for many years.

Comment: The answer can lead to flame wars, same as asking if you should go with Vim (of course!) rather than Emacs (yuck!). Personally I prefer IDEA because the updates don't break plugins so often as it appears to happen in NetBeans. YMMV